# Is it normal for Kibana to load 131 js files?

Tags: kibana

Looking at chrome network tab, Kibana loads 131 js files.
Is this a normal behavior for Kibana in production?

Can I bundle all these js somehow?

Comment: Sure, bundle them with Webpack, Parcel, or something else.

Comment: do you know how to do that with Kibana?

Comment: If it's like any other web component you just set up your packer properly and it will "compile" all of the JS, CSS, etc. assets into your final pack(s). I don't know why this would be special.

Comment: Kibana is a whole product. Maybe there is a configuration to bundle it's JS files

Comment: Sure, but as far as these packer tools are concerned they don't care what it is, product or plugin or whatever. They just operate on files.